# How do I add a new line to richTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a mouse down event and I'm writing text to richTextBox:

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Rectangle Location: " + e.Location + Environment.NewLine;
            Bitmap bmp;
            Point pnt;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                cm.Show(pictureBoxSnap, e.Location);

                return;
            }

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (checkError(listBox1.SelectedIndex, "pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown") == true) { return; } //if listBox1 empty

                if (isCroppedList[listBox1.SelectedIndex] == true) { return; }

                mouseDown = e.Location;

                if (canDrawNormallyList[listBox1.SelectedIndex] == false)
                {
                    bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSnap.Width - 4, pictureBoxSnap.Height - 4);

                    pnt = PointToScreen(pictureBoxSnap.Location);

                    g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

                    g.CopyFromScreen(pnt.X + 2, pnt.Y + 2, 0, 0, new Size(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

                    g.Dispose();

                    windowsBitmaps[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = bmp;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (thumb != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
                        MessageBoxIcon icon = MessageBoxIcon.Error;

                        MessageBox.Show("ERROR in pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown: thumb != IntPtr.Zero", "ERROR", buttons, icon);

                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In the mouse down event I'm writing the location of the rectangle.

Then in the DrawRectangle method I want to display in the richTextBox1 in real time the size of the rectangle:

```
private void DrawRectangle(Point pnt)
        {
            g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

            g.Clear(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control));

            if (pnt.X == mouseDown.X || pnt.Y == mouseDown.Y)
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, mouseDown.X, mouseDown.Y, pnt.X, pnt.Y);
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, Math.Min(mouseDown.X, pnt.X), Math.Min(mouseDown.Y, pnt.Y),
                            Math.Abs(mouseDown.X - pnt.X), Math.Abs(mouseDown.Y - pnt.Y));
                richTextBox1.Text = "Rectangle Size: " + Math.Abs(mouseDown.X - pnt.X) +
                    Math.Abs(mouseDown.Y - pnt.Y);
            }

            g.Dispose();

            g = frm.CreateGraphics();

            g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);

            g.Dispose();
        }
```

The problem now is that when i make mouse down left click on mouse button i see the location but then when i  move the mouse around drag it around the location line is deleted and i see the size line instead. If in the DrawRectangle method i also make += it's just adding the size line many time fill the whole richTextBox with that when i move/drag the mouse aorund.

Comment: richTextBox1.Text += "Rectangle Location: " + e.Location + Environment.NewLine;
Use this syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append each time. What you're doing currently is overwriting the text that is already there.

This:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Rectangle Location: " + e.Location + Environment.NewLine;
```

..says: "The value of the richtextbox text must ONLY be what I've provided.

This however:

```
richTextBox1.Text += "Rectangle Location: " + e.Location + Environment.NewLine;
//               ^^^^ append
```

..says: "The richtextbox text must be what it currently is ... plus this extra stuff."

Comment: Simon it did add both lines but the second one first and the first one near to it but in the first line. It didnt add it to a new line. It look like for example: Size: 22,22Location: 233,44    both on the first line.

Comment: Make sure both of your other piece of code that writes the `Size` has the `+=` there too.

Comment: Simon i moved the Location line to mouse down event so it will show the location in the richTextBox once when i click the mouse left button. richTextBox1.Text += "Rectangle Location: " + e.Location + Environment.NewLine; same line in the mouse down event. And the second line is in the place it was in the DrawRectangle method now when i click the mouse left button i see the location but then when i move the mouse drag the mouse the line is delete and instead i see the size line from the DrawRectangle method.

Comment: Simon if im doing in the second one also += it's appending the text many lines fill it with lines.

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag variable.

```
int flag=0;
if(flag==0)
{
richTextBox1.Text += "Rectangle Location: " + e.Location;
flag++;
}
else
{
richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Rectangle Location: " + e.Location + ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to give you some advice. When using if statement, it is unneccessary to do if (isCroppedList[listBox1.SelectedIndex] == true) when you can just use
if (isCroppedList[listBox1.SelectedIndex] ).
The solution that might be solve your problem could be: Check if the Multiline is set to True,or try richTextBox.AppendText(txt).